# Cisco ASA Firewall VPN connection issue

Tags: vpn, dns, firewall, connection

Sometimes when my co-workers and I connect to the LAN at work from home, we get this weird issue.

The VPN connection is established without error, but we cant do a remote desktop on the machines in the LAN.

*Example:* I'm working at home and suddenly I can't see my pc at work. I can disconnect and connect my VPN without getting any errors. But remote desktop cant connect to machines at the LAN.

An nslookup does not return the local ip-addresses.

So far I have been able to solve the problem by restarting the firewall, or in rare cases it helps restarting the PC.

This only happens sometimes, why? And am I able to reset a single VPN session in our Cisco ASA Firewall if the session 'hangs'?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to ping the rdp hosts ip?

Comment: Not the private IP

Answer (score 1):

1. Logon to the server locally
2. Click Start, Run, type `tscc.msc /s` (without quotation marks) and click OK
3. In the Terminal Services Configuration snap-in double-click Connections, then RDP-Tcp in the right pane
4. Click the Network Adapter tab, select the correct network adapter and click OK
5. Make sure that you can establish an RDP connection to the server

Comment: So I have to do this on all the machines in the network?